# Calculating the density of data points around a specified point in a $k$-dimensional space

Tags: vector-spaces, data-analysis

I am looking for a way of calculating how close data points are to a specified point in a $k$-dimensional space. My current method involves Pythagorean to calculate the distance between the specified point and each of the data points. However, when working with an order of $10,000$ data points this is very computationally intensive and is too slow for my program.
Does anyone have suggestions for an alternative algorithm to use to determine a point's proximity to other data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304686/calculating-the-density-of-data-points-around-a-specified-point-in-a-k-dimension

Comment: How big is $k?$ I wouldn't have thought 10000 data points would be that computationally expensive. Perhaps you could vectorize your operations?

Comment: Hi Adrian,
K would be approximately equal to 10, so would involved a fair amount of arithmetic calculations. Thanks for your help, I can see if combining all the calculations into vectors would speed things up little.